# how to print $scope data in html

Tags: angularjs

I want to print $scope.data in my html so how is it possible?

```
$scope.getdata=function(val){
    $location.url('/page/profile');
       var url = "example.com";
       var data= this.user;
       var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
                'x-api-key': '123456'
            }
        }

      $http.post(url, data, config).then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $scope.data=data;

      }) };
```

**HTML Code hear i want to print data which get from controller function**

```
<div class="page page-profile" ng-controller="ProfileController">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="panel mini-box">
            <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-round btn-icon-lg-alt bg-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="box-info">
                <p class="text-muted">Phone</p>
                <p class="size-h4">{{ data }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>                    
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: yes  we can use scope object values in double angular braces like {{ your field /objectname }}

Comment: Check out the http req. Debug and check whether you can get response. If not,http fails. Add your html code as well. I help to solve your issue.

Comment: Add this piece in html :<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>

Comment: Lose the spaces in `{{ data }}`

Comment: What's the CSS for class "size-h4" ?

Comment: i removed this class but nothing work
<p >{{ data }}</p>

Answer (score 2):

Angular has a built-in `filter` for showing JSON

In Html:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure - in your HTML, you just put `{{data}}`.

That's how you show the value of a `$scope` variable.

But this is really a ***very*** basic question. You should do more research before posting.

Comment: {{data}} not working

Note : this function is in the controller

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What happened? Why is that wrong?

Comment: Then try `$scope` or press F12 to open the developer console, set a breakpoint on the line `$scope.data=data;` - you will probably not stop there, because I imagine that your HTTP request is failing.

Comment: in console i can print data but not in html

Comment: Then I think that you need to show us your HTML (which you should have done in the first place); please update the question to show it. And don't forget to add code to handle that HTTP request failing

Answer (score 0):

you change the $scope with $rootScope and also add it as depencendy in your controller.

Comment: can you give me example ? plz 
because i am new ina angularjs